# Loading large zipped data-set using dask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, dask

I am trying to load a large zipped data set into python with the following structure:

- year.zip

  - year

    - month

      - a lot of .csv files

So far I have used the ZipFile library to iterate through each of the CSV files and load them using pandas.

```
zf = ZipFile(year.zip)

for file in zf.namelist:
    try:
        pd.read_csv(zf.open(file))
```

It takes ages and I am looking into optimizing the code. One option I ran into is to use dask library. However, I can't figure out how to best implement it to access at least the whole month of CSV files in one command. Any suggestions? Also open to other optimization approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The most similar to your suggestion would be something like:

```
zf = ZipFile("year.zip")
files = list(zf.namelist)
parts = [dask.delayed(pandas.read_csv)(f) for f in files)]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

This works because a zipfile has a offset listing, so that the component files can be read independently; however, performance may depend on how the archive was created, and remember: you only have one storage device, to throughput from the device may be your bottleneck anyway.

Perhaps a more daskian method to do this is as follows, taking advantage of the features of `fsspec`, the file-system abstraction used by dask

```
df = dd.read_csv('zip://*.csv', storage_options={'fo': 'year.zip'})
```

(of course, pick the glob pattern appropriate for your files; you could also use a list of files here, if you prepend "zip://" to them)